# Random irrational number generator?

Tags: algorithms, random, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Is it possible to create a algorithm that will generate irrational numbers $0<x<1$ with a density that is uniform down a specified resolution?

Would such an algorithm be necessarily limited to irrational, non-transcendental numbers?

If we wanted to make it possible to generate transcendental numbers, how would our algorithm express them, and would they "outnumber" the non-transcendental numbers so much that all outputs would be almost surely transcendental?

How would we prove that the distribution was uniform down to our specified resolution?

Comment: How do you represent irrational numbers? Remember, uncountably many numbers can't be expressed in any given human-comprehensible system. I doubt it's possible to be clever enough in the representation to do this.

Comment: @PatrickStevens  Roots, maybe summations.  That's part of the trickery I'm hoping people will come up with.

Comment: But you can only represent countably many numbers that way. However you specify a representational system, you will miss out uncountably many numbers: there will be uncountably many numbers which can simply never be picked. In the same way, we can't draw numbers from a uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$, but have to approximate the distribution by a discrete one.

Comment: @PatrickStevens  Yeah, that's why I said "down to a specified resolution",

Comment: If $x≠0$ is rational, then $e^x$ is transcendental...so if you can generate random rational numbers you can exponentiate them to get random transcendentals.  Of course uniform rationals will give non-uniform results here.  Is this the sort of thing you had in mind?

Comment: Note:  the non-uniformity is not a big problem.  To make it (roughly) uniform, choose a random rational $x$ uniformly, take its log, then take a very good rational approximation to that and exponentiate it.  You will get a transcendental number arbitrarily close to your original rational.

Comment: "down to a specified resolution", every number is rational.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Oh, but I mean the density is uniform down to a specified resolution.  The numbers we output can be in root, exponential, summation, or whatever form so they'll be truly irrational.

Comment: @lulu: "choose a random rational $x$ uniformly": How? I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @TonyK Oh, just bound the denominator.  There are approximations at each stage...nothing in the operation is exact.

Comment: @lulu: Bounding the denominator doesn't give a uniform distribution. For example, $\{0,1/3,1/2,2/3,1\}$ is not uniform.

Comment: @TonyK so pick an integer uniformly between $\{0,N\}$ and take $\frac iN$.  Do you really see a problem here?  As I say, there are approximations at each stage (log, continued fraction, exp).  I'd have said that picking the rational was the least controversial point.

Comment: @lulu: well, you might as well get the first step right!

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the integer number of choices you want (the "resolution").  Let $Z$ be a random integer in the set $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$, equally likely over all options.  Define $X = \pi Z/(4n)$.  Then $X$ is the random irrational number you want.

---

I guess if you wanted it to have a density function, rather than a probability mass function, you could define $U$ as the standard uniform random variable over $(0,1)$ and define: 
$$ X = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
U & \mbox{ if $U$ is irrational} \\
\pi/4 & \mbox{ if $U$ is rational} 
\end{array}\right. $$
Then $U$ and $X$ have the same CDF and the same density.

Comment: That method doesn't make the distribution uniform on 0<x<1.

Comment: For the first method, we have $X$ is an irrational number that satisfies $0<X<1$ and has $n$ equally likely options. For the second method, $X$ is irrational and has CDF $F_X(x) = x$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking no, if it's an uniform distribution over an interval of $\mathbb R$ it's almost certain that the outcome could not be encoded (with whatever coding method you've choosen).

But if you as you say settle for "up to specified precision" then you've a situation where inclusion of irrationals doesn't make any difference. You just use a standard random number generator that generate random number with given precision. For example if you use two decimal precision you have to make sure that $0.01$ happens with $1\%$ probability (special cases are $0.00$ and $1.00$ that would have $0.5\%$ probability).

Answer (score 0):

pick a random rational number in (0,1) with the desired resolution.

pick your favourite  trigonometric function and your favourite range for the arguments.

scale the rational to the range (such that (0,1) scales to your chosen range).

(!) compute the (transcendental) result of applying the function to the scaled argument

Accept the result with a probability inversely proportional to the density probability of the result from step (!).

Scale linearly to (0,1).

---

E.g.

Generate $a$ in (0,1).

Compute sin($a$).

Accept the result with probability cos($a$). (if result is rejected start from the beginning)

Divide result by sin($1$).

(the adjustment of probability can be done alternatively in the rational picking phase - accept $a$ with cos($a$) probability.  The resolution of the picking process should/could be adjusted to yield the desired result resolution).

Answer (score 0):

Under the hypothesis that $\pi$ is a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), you can shift the decimal expression of $\pi$:
$$
a_0=\pi, \qquad a_{n+1} = \operatorname{frac}(10a_n)
$$

Instead of $\pi$, you can also use the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant), which is known to be normal.